# How can I reference a function in Vue 3 within an HTML string? (google maps info window)

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, google-maps, vuejs3

I am using Vue 3 and google maps js API.

My goal is to click on a marker, which opens up an info window, and in that window have a button that the user can click to run some code.

I made a custom HTML element to go inside of the infowindow that gets created when clicking a marker. But I can not reference my function in this custom html.

How can I reference my function within the custom html?

```
<script setup>
/* eslint-disable no-undef */
import { computed, ref, onMounted, onUnmounted, watch, reactive, toRaw } from 'vue'
import { useMapStore } from '../pinia/map'

import { Loader } from '@googlemaps/js-api-loader'

const mapStore = useMapStore()

//~~ MAPPING ~ load API
const GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY = import.meta.env.VITE_GAPI
const loader = new Loader({
  apiKey: GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY,
  version: 'beta',
  libraries: ['marker']
})

const mapDiv = ref(null) // define divref to populate the map
let map = mapStore.map // get map from pinia store to persist map


const initMap = async () => {
  await loader.load()

  map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv.value, {
    center: { lat: 40, lng: -80 },
    zoom: 4,
    maxZoom: 19,
    minZoom: 3
  })

  // create a new marker with custom content for the info window
  const marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: { lat: 40, lng: -80 },
    map: map,
    title: 'My Marker'
  })

  // create a new info window with custom HTML content
  const infoWindowContent = '<div><h3>My Marker Info Window</h3><button onclick="testFx()" >WORK</button></div>'
  const infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: infoWindowContent
  })

  // add an event listener to open the info window when the marker is clicked
  marker.addListener('click', () => {
    infoWindow.open(map, marker)
  })

}

//~ initialize map 
onMounted(async () => {
  await initMap()
})

const testFx = () =>{
  console.log('something worked');
}

</script>

<template>
  <div style="overflow-y: hidden">
    <div ref="mapDiv" style="background-color: #4CAF50; width: 100%; height: 90vh"></div>
  </div>
</template>
```

This code does everything I need it to besides run the function. I get this error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: testFx is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick
```

Comment: You can't do it this way. Fortunately, you can expect that html can be passed not just as text in such cases. "content contains either a string of text or a DOM node to display in the info window"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this issue by using this code:

```
    marker.addListener('click', () => {
      infoWindow.open(map, marker)

      // add event listener when InfoWindow content is ready
      google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(infoWindow, 'domready', () => {
        const button = document.getElementById('my-button')
        button.addEventListener('click', () => {

          console.log('PUT FUNCTION HERE')

        })
      })
    })
```

Now I can reference functions within the google maps infowindow